# Converting from a double to an integer for bitwise operations?

Tags: vba, excel

Unfortunately, I have to do this all in VBA for Excel, but I'm trying to figure out if there is a way take a number that is normally an unsigned integer in any other language, do some things (add, multiply, etc.) to it as a `double` in VBA, and then convert that back to a `Long` in VBA that would be the bitwise equivalent of it as an unsigned long so that I can do some bitwise operations (particular xor) on it.

I'd gladly just make some kind of a DLL to call into it if I could, but it's just not going to be possible in this environment.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Why does it need to be a double?  What is its range?  Have you considered using the [`Decimal` data type?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx)

Comment: The numbers are larger than 2^31, but still less than 2^32.

Comment: I didn't know about the `Decimal` type.  I'll play around with that.  It might work.

Comment: `Decimal` has a 96 significant-bit resolution.

Comment: Ugh, VBA doesn't seem to recognize the `Decimal` type.

Comment: Create a `Variant` whose subtype is `Decimal` using the `CDec` function

Comment: Ah, thank you, that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar need while attempting to implement hashes in VBA.  I was frustrated at the lack of shifts, rorates and multi-byte logical operations. I created a `ByteSet` class and used it to build a `CDbltoLng`function.

Here is the conversion function. Information on the format of doubles can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Place this in a standard module:

```
Public Function CDblToLng(num As Double) As Long

    Dim DblBytes As clsByteSet
    Set DblBytes = New clsByteSet
    DblBytes.fromDouble num

    Dim SignMask As clsByteSet
    Dim ExponentMask As clsByteSet
    Dim MantissaMask As clsByteSet

    Set SignMask = New clsByteSet
    Set ExponentMask = New clsByteSet
    Set MantissaMask = New clsByteSet

    SignMask.fromCustomBytes &H80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ExponentMask.fromCustomBytes &H7F, &HF0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    MantissaMask.fromCustomBytes 0, &HF, &HFF, &HFF, &HFF, &HFF, &HFF, &HFF

    Dim negative As Byte
    negative = DblBytes.Clone.AND_ByteSet(SignMask).ShiftRight(63).toByte

    Dim ExponentInteger As Integer
    ExponentInteger = DblBytes.Clone.AND_ByteSet(ExponentMask).ShiftRight(52).toInteger - 1023

    Dim LongNumber As Long
    LongNumber = DblBytes.Clone.AND_ByteSet(MantissaMask).ShiftRight(52 - ExponentInteger).toLong

    If negative Then
        If ExponentInteger = 31 Then
            CDblToLng = (Not (LongNumber Or &H80000000)) + 1
        Else
            CDblToLng = (Not (LongNumber Or 2 ^ ExponentInteger)) + 1 'Or (IIf(negative, -1, 1) * 2 ^ ExponentInteger)
        End If
    Else
        If ExponentInteger = 31 Then
            CDblToLng = LongNumber Or &H80000000
        Else
            If ExponentInteger <= 30 Then
                CDblToLng = LongNumber Or 2 ^ ExponentInteger
            Else
                CDblToLng = LongNumber
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

And here is `clsByteSet`.  You can pull in bytes from just about any numeric datatype in VBA and then manipulate the bytes as needed.

```
Option Compare Database

'Updated to be a Fluent Interface

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "Kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (dest As Any, source As Any, ByVal length As Long)

Private m_arrBytes() As Byte

Public Function Resize(n As Long) As clsByteSet
    ReDim m_arrBytes(0 To n - 1)
End Function

Public Function fromCustomBytes(ParamArray bytes()) As clsByteSet
    ReDim m_arrBytes(0 To UBound(bytes))
    For i = 0 To UBound(bytes)
        m_arrBytes(i) = CByte(bytes(i))
    Next

    Set fromCustomBytes = Me
End Function

Public Function fromDouble(Dbl As Double) As clsByteSet
    ReDim m_arrBytes(0 To 7)
    For i = 0 To 7
        CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(m_arrBytes(i)), ByVal CLng(VarPtr(Dbl) + (7& - i)), 1
    Next

    Set fromDouble = Me
End Function

Public Function fromLong(lng As Long) As clsByteSet
    ReDim m_arrBytes(0 To 3)
    For i = 0 To 3
        CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(m_arrBytes(i)), ByVal CLng(VarPtr(lng) + (3& - i)), 1
    Next

    Set fromLong = Me
End Function

Public Function fromInteger(intgr As Integer) As clsByteSet
    ReDim m_arrBytes(0 To 1)
    For i = 0 To 1
        CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(m_arrBytes(i)), ByVal CLng(VarPtr(intgr) + (1& - i)), 1
    Next

    Set fromInteger = Me
End Function

Public Function fromByte(b As Byte) As clsByteSet
    ReDim m_arrBytes(0 To 1 - 1)
    m_arrBytes(0) = b

    Set fromByte = Me
End Function

Public Function fromBytes(b() As Byte) As clsByteSet
    ReDim m_arrBytes(LBound(b) To UBound(b))
    For i = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
        m_arrBytes(i) = b(i)
    Next

    Set fromBytes = Me
End Function

Public Property Get bytes() As Byte()
    bytes = m_arrBytes
End Property

Public Property Get bytesbyte(index As Long) As Byte
    bytesbyte = m_arrBytes(index)
End Property

Public Function Clone() As clsByteSet
    Set Clone = New clsByteSet
    Clone.fromBytes m_arrBytes
End Function

Public Function toBytes() As Byte()
    ReDim toBytes(LBound(m_arrBytes) To UBound(m_arrBytes))
    For i = LBound(m_arrBytes) To UBound(m_arrBytes)
        toBytes(i) = m_arrBytes(i)
    Next
End Function

Public Function toByte() As Byte
    Dim b As Byte
    b = m_arrBytes(UBound(m_arrBytes))
    toByte = b
End Function

Public Function toInteger() As Integer
    Dim intgr As Integer
    For i = 0 To 1
        CopyMemory ByVal CLng(VarPtr(intgr) + (1& - i)), ByVal VarPtr(m_arrBytes(i + UBound(m_arrBytes) - 1)), 1
    Next
    toInteger = intgr
End Function

Public Function toLong() As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    For i = 0 To 3
        CopyMemory ByVal CLng(VarPtr(lng) + (3& - i)), ByVal VarPtr(m_arrBytes(i + UBound(m_arrBytes) - 3)), 1
    Next
    toLong = lng
End Function

Public Function toDouble() As Double
    Dim Dbl As Double
    For i = 0 To 7
        CopyMemory ByVal CLng(VarPtr(Dbl) + (7& - i)), ByVal VarPtr(m_arrBytes(i + UBound(m_arrBytes) - 7)), 1
    Next
    toDouble = Dbl
End Function

Public Function toString() As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim i As Long
    If UBound(m_arrBytes) > 0 Then
        strOutput = right("0" & Hex(m_arrBytes(0)), 2)
        i = 1
        While i <= UBound(m_arrBytes)
            strOutput = strOutput & " " & right("0" & Hex(m_arrBytes(i)), 2)
            i = i + 1
        Wend
    End If
    toString = strOutput
End Function

'************************************************************************************************************************************
'* Bitwise Boolean *
'*******************

Public Function XOR_ByteSet(bs As clsByteSet) As clsByteSet
    For i = 0 To UBound(bs.bytes)
        m_arrBytes(i) = m_arrBytes(i) Xor bs.bytes(i)
    Next

    Set XOR_ByteSet = Me
End Function

Public Function AND_ByteSet(bs As clsByteSet) As clsByteSet
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(bs.bytes)
        m_arrBytes(i) = m_arrBytes(i) And bs.bytesbyte(i)
    Next

    Set AND_ByteSet = Me
End Function

Public Function OR_ByteSet(bs As clsByteSet) As clsByteSet
    For i = 0 To UBound(bs.bytes)
        m_arrBytes(i) = m_arrBytes(i) Or bs.bytes(i)
    Next

    Set OR_ByteSet = Me
End Function


'************************************************************************************************************************************
'* Shifts and Rotates *
'**********************

Public Function ShiftRight(length As Long) As clsByteSet
'Inefficient because it performs two operations: shift bytes then shift bits
    If length > UBound(m_arrBytes) + 1 Then
        'Error
    End If

    Dim shiftbits As Byte
    Dim shiftbytes As Long


    shiftbytes = length \ 8
    shiftbits = length Mod 8

    Dim i As Long

    If shiftbytes > 0 Then

        For i = UBound(m_arrBytes) To shiftbytes Step -1
            m_arrBytes(i) = m_arrBytes(i - shiftbytes)
        Next
        For i = shiftbytes - 1 To 0 Step -1
            m_arrBytes(i) = 0
        Next

    End If

    If shiftbits > 0 Then

        For i = UBound(m_arrBytes) To 1 Step -1
            m_arrBytes(i) = ShiftByteRight(m_arrBytes(i), shiftbits) Or ShiftByteLeft(m_arrBytes(i - 1), 8 - shiftbits)
        Next
        m_arrBytes(0) = ShiftByteRight(m_arrBytes(i), shiftbits)

    End If

    Set ShiftRight = Me
End Function

Public Function ShiftLeft(length As Long) As clsByteSet
'Inefficient because it performs two operations: shift bytes then shift bits
    If length > UBound(m_arrBytes) + 1 Then
        'Error
    End If
    Dim shiftbits As Byte
    Dim shiftbytes As Long

    shiftbytes = length \ 8
    shiftbits = length Mod 8

    Dim i As Long

    If shiftbytes > 0 Then

        For i = 0 To UBound(m_arrBytes) - shiftbytes
            m_arrBytes(i) = m_arrBytes(i + shiftbytes)
        Next
        For i = UBound(m_arrBytes) - shiftbytes To UBound(m_arrBytes)
            m_arrBytes(i) = 0
        Next

    End If

    If shiftbits > 0 Then

        For i = 0 To UBound(m_arrBytes) - 1
            m_arrBytes(i) = ShiftByteLeft(m_arrBytes(i), shiftbits) Or ShiftByteRight(m_arrBytes(i + 1), 8 - shiftbits)
        Next
        m_arrBytes(i) = ShiftByteLeft(m_arrBytes(i), shiftbits)

    End If

    Set ShiftLeft = Me
End Function

Public Function RotateRight(length As Long) As clsByteSet
'Inefficient because it performs two operations: shift bytes then shift bits
    If length > (UBound(m_arrBytes) + 1) * 8 Then
        length = length Mod (UBound(m_arrBytes) + 1)
    End If
    Dim shiftbits As Byte
    Dim shiftbytes As Long

    shiftbytes = length \ 8
    shiftbits = length Mod 8

    Dim i As Long

    If shiftbytes > 0 Then

        Dim temparr() As Byte
        ReDim temparr(0 To shiftbytes - 1)
        For i = 0 To shiftbytes - 1
            temparr(i) = m_arrBytes(i + (UBound(m_arrBytes) - (shiftbytes - 1)))
        Next
        For i = UBound(m_arrBytes) To shiftbytes Step -1
            m_arrBytes(i) = m_arrBytes((i - shiftbytes))
        Next
        For i = shiftbytes - 1 To 0 Step -1
            m_arrBytes(i) = temparr(i)
        Next

    End If

    If shiftbits > 0 Then

        Dim tempbyte As Byte
        tempbyte = ShiftByteLeft(m_arrBytes(UBound(m_arrBytes)), 8 - shiftbits)
        For i = UBound(m_arrBytes) To 1 Step -1
            m_arrBytes(i) = ShiftByteLeft(m_arrBytes(i - 1), 8 - shiftbits) Or ShiftByteRight(m_arrBytes(i), shiftbits)
        Next
        m_arrBytes(0) = ShiftByteRight(m_arrBytes(0), shiftbits) Or tempbyte

    End If

    Set RotateRight = Me
End Function

Public Function RotateLeft(length As Long) As clsByteSet
'Inefficient because it performs two operations: shift bytes then shift bits
    If length > (UBound(m_arrBytes) + 1) * 8 Then
        length = length Mod (UBound(m_arrBytes) + 1)
    End If
    Dim shiftbits As Byte
    Dim shiftbytes As Long

    shiftbytes = length \ 8
    shiftbits = length Mod 8

    Dim i As Long

    If shiftbytes > 0 Then

        Dim temparr() As Byte
        ReDim temparr(0 To shiftbytes - 1)
        For i = 0 To shiftbytes - 1
            temparr(i) = m_arrBytes(i)
        Next
        For i = 0 To UBound(m_arrBytes) - shiftbytes
            m_arrBytes(i) = m_arrBytes((i + shiftbytes))
        Next
        For i = 0 To shiftbytes - 1
            m_arrBytes(i + UBound(m_arrBytes) - (shiftbytes - 1)) = temparr(i)
        Next

    End If

    If shiftbits > 0 Then

        Dim tempbyte As Byte
        tempbyte = ShiftByteRight(m_arrBytes(0), 8 - shiftbits)
        For i = 0 To UBound(m_arrBytes) - 1
            m_arrBytes(i) = ShiftByteLeft(m_arrBytes(i), shiftbits) Or ShiftByteRight(m_arrBytes(i + 1), 8 - shiftbits)
        Next
        m_arrBytes(UBound(m_arrBytes)) = ShiftByteLeft(m_arrBytes(UBound(m_arrBytes)), shiftbits) Or tempbyte

    End If

    Set RotateLeft = Me
End Function

Private Function ShiftByteRight(ByVal data As Byte, length As Byte) As Byte
    ShiftByteRight = data \ (2 ^ (length))
End Function

Private Function ShiftByteLeft(ByVal data As Byte, length As Byte) As Byte
    ShiftByteLeft = (data And ((2 ^ (8 - length)) - 1)) * (2 ^ length)
End Function
```

Comment: That does increase my algorithmic time complexity quite a bit, but it does what I want.

Comment: Why do you iterate through every byte of an object in `clsByteSet` when copying to `m_arrBytes` instead of just specifying the size as the last parameter to `CopyMemory`?

Comment: @supercheetah See this wikipedia article: [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  The bytes of the Double/Long/Integer are stored in Little Endian in memory.  For example the long value &H0A0B0C0D would be stored as those 4 individual bytes in reverse order: |0D|0C|0B|0A|.  Looking back on it now, I'm sure the Win32 api must provide a better way, but I wanted to finalize the interface of my class and worry about optimizing the implementation later.  If you have any suggestions, let me know!

Comment: Ah, yes, endianness.  That makes sense.  An alternative would be to make sure that your bitwise functions account for this by iterating through them in reverse order, or even copying those memory regions to Longs or Ints, and doing the bitwise operations on those instead.